# Is it possible to always have fastscroll enabled in a listview?

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view which uses an adapter that implements the SectionIndexer. This in combination with setting my list view to have fast scroll enabled, allows me to quickly scroll through the list the same way as it happens in the Contacts Activity.

Under a certain number of items though, the regular scroll is what shows up instead of the fast scroll(confirmed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200501/not-able-to-get-fast-scrolling-working-on-expandablelistview)). My question is, is there a way in **Android 2.2 - Froyo** to have the fast scroll always show up.

I know that in Honeycomb, there is a method to always have the fast scroll enabled - [setFastScrollAlwaysVisible()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setFastScrollAlwaysVisible%28boolean%29) but I'm looking for one in Froyo.

Answer (score 0):

In xml file, for listview add

```
  android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `listview.setFastScrollEnabled(true)`